# Trying to test variable being set in callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write a simple jasmine test to test that `$scope.users` gets set in the callback of `Users.find`. In my last test below, `scope.users` is undefined so the test fails.

How can I test that `scope.users` gets set so my test passes?

controller

```
angular.module('web').controller('CardsCtrl',function($scope, $http, Users){

  /**
   * Get all users on page load
   */
  Users.find(function(users) {

    $scope.users = users;
});
```

Users service

```
(function(window, angular, undefined) {'use strict';

var urlBase = "http://localhost:3333/api";

var module = angular.module("services", ['ngResource']);
module.factory(
  "Users",
  ['LoopBackResource', 'LoopBackAuth', '$injector', function(Resource, LoopBackAuth, $injector) {
    var R = Resource(
      urlBase + "/users/:id",
      { 'id': '@id' },
      {
        "find": {
          url: urlBase + "/users",
          method: "GET",
          isArray: true,
        },
      }
  );

  return R;
}]);
```

spec

```
describe('CardsCtrl', function() {

  var scope, ctrl, users;

  beforeEach(module('web'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, Users) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    users = Users;
    spyOn(users, 'find');
    ctrl = $controller('CardsCtrl', {$scope: scope, Users: users});
  }));


  describe('the cards controller being instantiated', function() {

    it('should be defined', function() {
      expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('tracks that the spy was called', function() {
      expect(users.find).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('fetches user data and assigns it to scope.users', function(done) {
      console.log('users= '+scope.users); // <-- THIS RETURNS UNDEFINED
      expect(scope.users).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: Can you post the code related to the Users service?

Comment: It already is. It's the middle snippet of code. It's pretty much just a service wrapped around a Resource.

Comment: I believe you need to use [`$httpBackend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) to simulate the response your service would return.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `.andCallThrough()` on the spy, and use `$httpBackend` to mock http response:

```
describe('CardsCtrl', function() {

    var scope, ctrl, users, httpBackend;

    beforeEach(module('web'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, Users, $httpBackend) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        users = Users;
        spyOn(users, 'find').andCallThrough();
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        httpBackend.expectGET(urlBase + '/users').respond(200, ['user1', 'user2']);
        ctrl = $controller('CardsCtrl', {$scope: scope, Users: users});
    }));

    afterEach(function() {
        httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    describe('the cards controller being instantiated', function() {

        ... // other tests

        it('fetches user data and assigns it to scope.users', function(done) {
            httpBackend.flush();
            expect(scope.users).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });

});
```

The mock `$httpBackend` is provided by [ngMock](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock) service, so you need to include `angular-mock.js` to run the test.

Comment: So if i use `andCallThrough()`, it actually goes through my callback method? What if I had multiple callback methods, like a success or failure? Can you explain why I need to use the httpBackend mock?

Comment: @Catfish Unit tests need to run as quickly as possible and shouldn't depend on the availability of external services, so you don't want to make real http requests in unit tests. The $httpBackend is created for that purpose. See angular docs for more details: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend